# How to check if a cell value is Chinese text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a list of cells which contain the first name of users: `Amy`, `Jim`, `梅`, `明`, `ธนกาญจน์`, `Андрей`, etc. From the name, I would like to determine if a user is Chinese.

Does anyone know if there is any formula or VBA method to determine this?

Comment: Do you have a list of chinese names to compare with?

Comment: No, I don't have

Comment: Then what you are asking is difficult. Having a chinese name does not mean the person is chinese, juts like having an english names does not mean the person is english.

Comment: Let's assume that having a Chinese name is Chinese here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use regular expression to test the cell characters. The code below test the characters. If they are found on the [CJK Unicode Tables](https://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tbluni.php?page=0). If found, they must be chinese.

```
Function IsChinese(myname As Range)

    Dim myregex As New RegExp

    myregex.Pattern = "[\u4E00-\u9FFF]+"
    IsChinese = myregex.Test(myname.Value)

End Function
```

[image: IsChinese function result]

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution... I'm thinking how to do if the list contains russian names or arabic names, etc.

Comment: @SoftTimur See edit.

Comment: nice... thank you...

Comment: @SoftTimur I have modified the regex pattern. Check if it still works.